# Custom module embedding existing node form

Tags: 7, forms, routes

I have the following content types:

- event
- signup

I'm dealing with my_singnup module, for which I wish to:

1. allow user to add signup content (same as core node/add/signup)
2. using signup/event/%eventid path (it is simple link expose in every event)
3. presenting (while adding) some information from event in left side
   and node/add/signup form on the right side
4. preventing signup/event without argument to run

The code I have already wrote is the following.

```
function my_singnup_menu() {
   $items = array();
   $items['signup/event'] = array(
     'title' => 'Sorry, no such event.',
     'page callback' => 'There is no event id in path.',
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     'access callback' => TRUE // for now
   );

   $items['signup/event/%eventid'] = array(
     'title' => 'Signing up for event',
     'title callback' => 'my_signup_title',
     'title arguments' => array(2),
     'page callback' => 'my_singnup',
     'page arguments' => array(2),
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     'access callback' => TRUE // for now
   );
   return $items;
}

function my_signup_title($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'event') {
  drupal_set_title(t('Signing up for event '.$node->title));
  }
  if ($node->type <> 'event') {
  drupal_set_title(t('Id in path is not event id.'));
  }
  return t('Signing up for event');
}

function my_signup($node = FALSE) {
   if($node) {
     if($node->type == 'event') {
       module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); //Added
       global $user; //Added
       $new_node = new stdClass; //Added
       $new_node->type = 'signup'; //Added - here was bug
       $new_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; //localization
       $new_node->user = $user->uid; //Added
       $new_node->name = (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''); //Added
       $form = drupal_get_form('signup_node_form', $new_node); //here was my big trouble
       return $form;
     }
   }
   return drupal_not_found();
}

function my_signup_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'signup_node_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'signup-node-form',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_signup'),
    ),
  );
}
```

<strike>Right now, I see some form under event/signup/999 (thats good), but there is no custom groups and fields like in core default node/add/signup. I was so happy to see it that I forget to check it looks the same. I see only core vertical tabs such as Menu, Book, Version, Adress, Comments, and there is no custom fields and groups in it. It is strange.</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`node_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) is in node.pages.inc which isn't included by default. Just add a call like this to the beginning of your `my_signup()` function:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```

When you call `drupal_get_form()` with a specific type (like `signup_node_form`) the node module internally translates that to `node_form()`. This happens in [`node_forms()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_forms/7) which is in the node.module file, and as such is always included.

However node.pages.inc is only included when specifically requested by a module/menu callback etc. so to use `node_form()` you'll need to include the file manually.

You also need to pass a node object to the function with the required content type assigned like the following code:

```
$new_node = new stdClass;
$new_node->type = 'signup';
$new_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$form = drupal_get_form('signup_node_form', $new_node);
```

Comment: So now I have to deal with missing arg, propably user...

Comment: @GregoryZbinsky I should have mentioned that sorry, I've updated the answer

Comment: Almost, I can see the form, there is only one object property to be set - language. Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$language w node_form(). And this will be very, very useful answer for all Drupalist

Comment: I've added the language part to the answer too, forgot about that one :)

Comment: There is one big ooops I've missed, when I was so happy to see signup_node_form: there is no custom groups and fields, only core... gosh!

Comment: Bug corrected, code works!

Comment: @GregoryZbinsky Nice one, glad you got it sorted :)